# objects/Opportunity.object (Opportunity.Reason_for_Loss__c) -- Error: duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>

Tags: custom-object, deployment, picklist

i am getting this error and have been trying to debug the cause for quite sometime now. I have scan through almost all the topics that google returned to me, but none help so far.

So, now i am trying to deploy only the problematics field/obj ([Opportunity.object](https://gist.github.com/okram999/90f81b6e3fbbd4797bb41b8f8dd11c7a)) and i am getting the same issue.

'Reason_fo_Loss__C' 's picklist was updated and am trying to deploy to another org.

i have disabled the history in the target org, as well as - set

```
  <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
  <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
```

There is no inactive fields with the same name too.

Any thoughts to resolve this will be appreciated.. thank you

Comment: anything new? i have digested this link

Comment: Ya all can mark this as a duplicate, if you know the solution. Having the same exception thrown, doesn't always mean its the same root cause (001 for software programming)